# If the current through a welder is hundreds of amps to melt metal, how does the welder circuitry cope

Tags: current, power-electronics, low-voltage, metal

A pretty simple question but i have no idea. My logic is if the current is so high where something as low resistance like a metal slab can be heated to melt. How on earth does the components in the welder not also melt?

Comment: What kind of welder you mean? Maybe the current isn't hundreds of amps like you think.

Comment: He must be talking about an electric welder.

Comment: @SteveSh Obviously yes - but which type? TIG, MIG, MAG, spot welding, other type of welding with electricity?

Comment: The copper wires in welder has lower resistivity than iron electrode. The wires are thicker also. Another plus is after arc is developed the welding point increase resistance because of heat.

Comment: `something as low resistance can be heated to melt` ... it's the other way around ... the heated area has higher resistance, so that is where most of the voltage is dropped ... the voltage drop along the wires is small, so there is little heating in the wires

Comment: Tungsten has a ridiculously high boiling point but can be *evaporated* with fractions of an amp in an electron beam. Interestingly, the electron beam itself is sourced from a very hot tungsten filament, then focused to a small spot where it hits the tungsten target material.

Answer (score 4):

It's not the current per-se, but the heat at the tip - the arc - that heats the metal and forms the weld.  The welding rod itself doesn't melt even with the several hundred amps through it.  The melting only occurs at the tip where the high temperature arc is.

Have you heard of relay contacts welding shut?  Same principle at work, only at a lower current & energy level.

Comment: So im assuming the impedance at the arc is a fair bit lower, hence heating up alot more?

Comment: That would be my guess.  In general when two conductors arc, the resistance between them drops very low.

Answer (score 3):

A simple spot welder might have an output like this. The wire on the secondary might be as big as a man's little finger.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnrnZX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>